# Is there a way to throttle data received by a Kafka consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, records, consumer, throttling

I was reading through docs and found a `max.poll.interval.ms` property but it doesn't seem to be the config that I need.

Basically, I need something like a `min.poll.interval.ms` to tell the consumer to poll for records every `n` second.

In conjunction with `max.poll.records`, I can ensure that my services are processing the right amount of load.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work this way.

You need to invoke `Consumer.poll(...)` periodically (in a loop), to get new records if any have appeared.

If you do record processing and receving (poll) in the same thread, then if the processing takes too long, your consumer will be thrown out of consumer group and another one will get the partitions.

---

An alternative is to use kafka-streams if you do not want to do that. Starting stream applications on different instances with the same `application id` will provide some kind of load balancing.

Comment: This answer assumes that you are ok with one consumer per partition. If that's not the case, you need to manage offsets on your own (and synchronise offset data across multiple consumers for that partition), what means even more work.